# How to detect which segment of a svg path is clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

SVG path element for example:

```
<path id="path1" 
d="M 160 180 C 60 140 230 20 200 170 C 290 120 270 300 200 240 C 160 390 50 240 233 196" 
stroke="#009900" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
```

It has 4 svg segments (3 curve segments in human eyes):

```
    M 160 180 
    C 60 140 230 20 200 170 
    C 290 120 270 300 200 240 
    C 160 390 50 240 233 196
```

when click on the path, I get the `x` and `y` of mouse position, then how to detect which curve segment is clicked?

```
    function isInWhichSegment(pathElement,x,y){
        //var segs = pathElement.pathSegList; //all segments
        //
        //return the index of which segment is clicked
        //
    }
```

Comment: You appear to have rejected the obvious solution of rendering each segment as a separate object. Can you explain why?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That solution need split the single path into many path elements and bring more questions when I handle the DOM nodes. I don't hope to create new elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods for **SVGPathElements** that you can use. Not really straighforward, but you could get the total length of your path, then check at every point of length the coordinates with **getPointAtLength** and compare it with coordinates of the click. Once you figure the click was at which length, you get the segment at that length with **getPathSegAtLength**. like that for example:

```js
 var pathElement = document.getElementById('path1')
 var len = pathElement.getTotalLength();

 pathElement.onclick = function(e) {
   console.log('The index of the clicked segment is', isInWhichSegment(pathElement, e.offsetX, e.offsetY))
 }

 function isInWhichSegment(pathElement, x, y) {
   var seg;
   // You get get the coordinates at the length of the path, so you
   // check at all length point to see if it matches
   // the coordinates of the click
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     var pt = pathElement.getPointAtLength(i);
     // you need to take into account the stroke width, hence the +- 2
     if ((pt.x < (x + 2) && pt.x > (x - 2)) && (pt.y > (y - 2) && pt.y < (y + 2))) {
       seg = pathElement.getPathSegAtLength(i);
       break;
     }
   }
   return seg;
 }
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="path1" d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="#009900" stroke-width="4" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this is a solution but inefficient. Is there a mathematical and efficient solution?

Comment: getPathSegAtLength deprecated :(